# Pyqt GUI Problem with High Resolution Screens

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, qt-designer

I've design my GUI with Qt Designer in low resolution screen (1366 * 768). But when I run my program in high resolution (high dpi) screens almost all fonts are messed up.

Login window in high dpi screen

[image: Login window in high dpi screen]

Login window in low resolution screen

[image: Login window in low resolution screen]

Create new user window in high dpi screen

[image: Create new user window in high dpi screen]

Create new user window in low resolution screen

[image: Create new user window in low resolution screen]

Product window in high dpi screen

[image: Product window in high dpi screen]

Product window in low resolution screen

[image: Product window in low resolution screen]

Any solution?

I've tried the below solution:
https://leomoon.com/journal/python/high-dpi-scaling-in-pyqt5/

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    app.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)
    app.setAttribute(Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps, True)

    login_window_started()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: How did you try to set those attributes? Specifically, when/where in the code? Please provide a [mre]. Also, you're not setting maximum sizes for those windows, are you?

Comment: Hi @musicamante, I've edited my post. So you can see where I've set those attributes.

Comment: As the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ApplicationAttribute-enum) explains, attributes such as `AA_EnableHighDpiScaling` *must* be set before the QApplication is constructed. Also please answer the other question.

Comment: since you didn't provide a minimal reproducible example I might be wrong, but it looks to me like you're placing your widgets using pixels, and not using spacers and layouts. Since the text in QT is affected by the zoom in the system (e.g. in windows gong to display and setting "change the size of text, apps, and other items" in the display settings), the widgets need to be able to adapt to this. So use spacers and layouts, and never set sizes and placements.

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution, you need to place these commands:

```
import PyQt5
from PyQt5 import Qtcore
PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)
```

as the first lines of your application (right under the imports).